# boolean trouble from different class

Tags: java, boolean

For my assignment question it is a method with the signature `public int applyNutrientCoefficient()`, that calculates which `Guppies` in the `Pool` have died of malnutrition, and returns the number of deaths.

Use an `Iterator<Guppy>` to iterate over the `guppiesInPool` in the `Pool`. For each `Guppy` generate a different random number between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive using the `Random` method `nextDouble()`. If this randomly generated
number is greater than the Pool's nutrient coeffcient, kill that `Guppy`
by setting the appropriate boolean field in the `Guppy`. Note that this
method does not remove any dead Guppies from the Pool, it just kills
them. Do not do anything else.

I have 2 classes one is `Guppy` one is `Pool`
in my guppy class I made a boolean  -

```
private boolean isAlive{}
public boolean getIsAlive(){ 
    return isAlive
}
```

in my Pool class....

```
public int applyNutrientCoefficient() 

int deathCount = 0

Iterator<Guppy> it = guppiesInPool.iterator()

while (it.hasNext() ) 

Guppy guppyOne = it.next()

    if (randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble() > nutrientCoefficient) 
    if (guppyOne.isAlive() ) 
    guppyOne.setAlive(false)
    deathCount++

    return deathCount
```

The error message I'm getting is cannot find symbol - method `isAlive()`

Can someone help please

Comment: What a mess, this is not valid java code. You are missing semicolons and brackets.

Answer (score 0):

you have to acces isAlive private field via the public getter that you provided getIsAlive()

In the Pool class

```
if (randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble() > nutrientCoefficient) 
if (guppyOne.isAlive() ) 
guppyOne.setAlive(false)
deathCount++

return deathCount
```

the line

```
if (guppyOne.isAlive() )
```

should instead be

```
if (guppyOne.getIsAlive() )
```

same thing with the setter: you need to provide a setter to the Guppy class and use that

```
public void setIsAlive(boolean alive){
this.isAlive = alive}
```

end result should be

```
if (randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble() > nutrientCoefficient) 
if (guppyOne.getIsAlive() ) 
guppyOne.setIsAlive(false)
deathCount++

return deathCount
```

Comment: i did do that i put getIsAlive() but for some reason still gave me same error.  how would i make the private isAlive to public?  i did                              public boolean getIsAlive() {
        return isAlive;

Comment: You also have to **call** `getIsAlive()` to publicly acces the current value of private `isAlive` field. BTW: even if it was public `isAlive()` would not compile because it is not a method but a field.

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to access in pool class the isAlive directly if (guppyOne.isAlive() )
when you should use the getter if (guppyOne.getIsAlive() )

Comment: im sorry im just confused. how would i call it?

Comment: if (guppyOne.isAlive() )         <-----     if (guppyOne.getIsAlive() ) 
guppyOne.setAlive(false)
deathCount++

Comment: @Zeromus better include the example in your answer than in a comment.

Comment: i put (guppyOne.getIsAlive() ) error im getting is cannot find symbol - method setAlive(false);  for the line guppyOne.setAlive(false); im getting the setAlive wrong

Comment: Is it really `private boolean isAlive{}` ? Has to be `private boolean isAlive;` Then do you have a setIsAlive method in guppy class?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems kinda off. It should be

```
private boolean isAlive; //private field, not a method.
public boolean getIsAlive() {  //public getter method.
    return isAlive;
}
public void setIsAlive(boolean isAlive) { //public setter method
    this.isAlive = isAlive;
}
```

Then,

```
public int applyNutrientCoefficient() {
    int deathCount = 0;
    Iterator it = guppiesInPool.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Guppy guppyOne = it.next();
        if (randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble() > nutrientCoefficient) {
            if (guppyOne.getIsAlive()) {
                guppyOne.setIsAlive(false);
                deathCount++; // should be inside the if-block i suppose?
            }
        }
    }

    return deathCount;
}
```

Also make sure you use semicolons and curly braces or the compiler will give you errors.