# changing milliliters to liters with if statement

Tags: java

hi for my assignment question which is 
a method with the header public double getGuppyVolumeRequirement()
which returns the total number of litres required by all of the living
Guppies in the Pool. Note that the Guppy class has a helpful method
with returns the total number of milliLitres required per Guppy. You
will need to convert this to litres (note that 1,000 mL = 1 L).

in my guppy class i did the code for millilitres which is:

```
public double getVolumeNeeded() {
        if (getAgeInWeeks() < YOUNG_FISH) {
            return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML;
        } else if (getAgeInWeeks() <= MATURE_FISH) {
            return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * getAgeInWeeks() / YOUNG_FISH;
        } else if (getAgeInWeeks() <= MAXIMUM_AGE_IN_WEEKS) {
            return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * 1.5;
        } else {
            return 0;
}
```

now im confused on how to make this to liters.
here is my return for guppies in pool

```
public int getPopulation() {
     return guppiesInPool.size();
}
```

Comment: thank you yassin but im a little confused, how would i input that into my code.

Comment: It seems that guppy question are very popular these days - [another guppy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009220/boolean-trouble-from-different-class/38009298#38009298). Maybe we shuold add a guppy tag?

Comment: @TDG Clearly we need a [tag:guppy] tag, and maybe a whole meta site for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1L = 1000mL you can convert between liters to milliLiters and viceversa with the following formulas:

```
litres = milliLitres / 1000;


milliLitres = litres * 1000;
```

---

In your code you can replace instructions like:

```
  return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML;    // Returns millilitres
```

With instructions like:

```
  return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML / 1000;   // Returns litres
```

Or for most complicated formulas:

```
 // Returns millilitres
 return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * getAgeInWeeks() / YOUNG_FISH;
```

Change to

```
 // Returns litres
 return (MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * getAgeInWeeks() / YOUNG_FISH) / 1000;
```

Comment: oh ok but what would my return be like my code, would it be  if (getAgeInWeeks() < YOUNG_FISH) {
            return litres = milliLitres * 1000;

Comment: sorry just really confused

Answer (score 0):

As you have a method which returns the millilitres required in your Guppy class, and 1L = 1000ml you may want to return

```
return liters = /* method which returns the total number of milliLitres required per Guppy */ / 1000;
```

if this `getVolumeNeeded()` method returns the millilitres you may want to have:

```
public double getVolumeNeeded() {
    if (getAgeInWeeks() < YOUNG_FISH) {
        return (MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML) / 1000;
    } else if (getAgeInWeeks() <= MATURE_FISH) {
        return (MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * getAgeInWeeks() / YOUNG_FISH) / 1000;
    } else if (getAgeInWeeks() <= MAXIMUM_AGE_IN_WEEKS) {
        return (MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML * 1.5) / 1000;
    } else {
        return 0;
}
```

All you need to do is divide every `return / 1000`

Comment: what would the method be for this specific code? sorry im new to java im just confused on this.

Comment: the method you said you had in your Guppy class that returns the millilitres.

Comment: yes its a long if statement would i have to copy and paste that into the grey area you said

Comment: thank you daniele when i did that getAgeInWeeks is giving me an error message cannot find symbol - method getAgeInWeeks()

Comment: the getAgeInWeeks() is in the guppy class that if statement is also.  im working in the pool class.  the liters conversion is suppose to be in the pool class

Comment: this depends on the if statement and probably on the `getAgeinWeeks()` method itself not the code I wrote. You may want to create a new question for that... Anyway if you found this answer helpful, please vote it up and accept it

Comment: thank you but what do you think is wrong in your opinion.  why you think its giving me the error.

Comment: I don't know if I can't see the `getAgeInWeeks()` method.

Comment: the method is public int getAgeInWeeks() {
        return ageInWeeks;
    } and my setter is public void setAgeInWeeks(int newAgeInWeeks) {
        if (newAgeInWeeks >= 0 && newAgeInWeeks <= MAXIMUM_AGE_IN_WEEKS) {
            ageInWeeks = newAgeInWeeks;
        }

Comment: As I said, you need to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

since you already got ml required per guppy, just return volume required in liters as `return MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML/1000`.